# indexpath as parameters

Tags: objective-c, nsindexpath

I got an table which is filled with VM's and i have 2 variable of the datatype NSIndexPath called: 
selectedindexpath(the row the user clicks on) and 
selectedindexpathFortheVMtoTurnOn(so it knows which row to reload when the VM went on);
which is both made in the .h as @paramters(retain) ..

i got a function that turns on the VM's and a function that CHECKS every 1 sec with a NSTimer if the guest is finally on then it reloads the row of selectedindexpathFortheVMtoTurnOn
im doing the same for OFF/REBOOT but i have got a problem with this.. im not able to request an action for more then 1 VM.. because it is overwriting the selectedindexpathFortheVMtoTurnOn value with the last row which i sent an action to and by doing so the table responds wierd and the app crashes..
so thats why i want to give the indexpath.row value as parameters with the NSTimer to the function that checks every 1 sec i have tried a few things but none have worked.. below the code of how i am giving the parameters

```
timertocallguest=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                            target:self
                          selector:@selector(gettheguestyouaskedforTOTURNON:)
                        userInfo:selectedindexpathFortheVMtoTurnOn
                                             repeats:YES];
```

and the function:

```
-(void)gettheguestyouaskedforTOTURNON:(NSIndexPath *)therow
```

and when i try to do a `NSLog("%d",therow.row);` it crashes...

and with `NSLog("%d",therow);` i get a whole diffrent value of the selectedindexpathFortheVMtoTurnOn that it used to had..

what am i doing wrong.?

sorry if its a wall of text. but i realy need to fix this problem as this is getting released as BETA nextweek in the appstore for the company where my traineeperiode is.

ty in advance.

EDIT:

i will try to show it with pictures this time.
At first im at the view with VM's
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/schermafbeelding2011052l.png/
after that i can press on the button with the arrow and i get to choose what i want to do.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/822/schermafbeelding2011052r.png/
an activity indicator appears and it stops when the action is done.(which has to do with the NStimer that checks every 1 sec)
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/828/schermafbeelding2011052y.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/schermafbeelding2011052t.png/
but when i try to do an action at 2 or more VM's the activity indicator on the last row i selected spins *x faster(depends on how manny actions i send.. 2 actions means it spins 2 times faster..(so weird)

.. i hope this is enough for you to understand what i mean now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method triggered by an `NSTimer` object always has the timer as the argument. You can get the row like this.

```
-(void)gettheguestyouaskedforTOTURNON:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)[timer userInfo];

    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: what do i need to give with the timer? userInfo:nil ?

Comment: `userInfo` should be as it is. Whatever you pass there will be retained. Since you want to send the index path, it should be the index path. We can then access the value you passed as argument there using the `userInfo` method of the timer. That is what I did in the code snippet.

Comment: thank you, i am able to give the indexpath as parameters but this did not fix my problem:(.

Comment: What is the error now? and what modifications did you make? Is `selectedindexpathFortheVMtoTurnOn` a valid index path?

Comment: i still cant send 2 or more actions to a VM, its still reloading the last row i gave action to instead of the row it belongs to. i dont know why it does this.. because i changed all the selectedindexpathFortheVMtoTurnOn in the function to the NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)[timer userInfo];

Comment: Can you update the question with the flow a bit? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: its all so complicated.. but i will try to edit my question above.

Comment: How are you referring to the activity indicator? I am assuming the timer method is getting the same index path based on what you're saying. Can you verify that? If you find it to be the same every time, can you check why the method creating the timer is sending the same argument.

Comment: Im customly making the activity indicator in the first line of the function and animating it in the row that i have selected and in the end of that function im checking if it went ON/OFF if so im setting the timer to invalidate and stopping the animation.., everytime im sending an action to the VM the NSTimer gets the indexpath of the row i select as the argument.

Comment: You will need to post the code from this method otherwise I really can't help you.

Comment: Change `timertocallguest` to `timer` in the method `gettheguestyouaskedforTOTURNON:` and let me know.

Comment: i changed [timertocallguest invalidate];
  timertocallguest = nil; 

to [timer invalidate];
timer = nil;  but its still not working properly..

Comment: See this is how I see it. Any ivars that you are relying on in the timer method is wrong. Say `selectedIndexPathForTheGuest` is set to row 1 first time and then soon after you do it for row 2, then the timer method for row 1 will see `selectedIndexPathFortheGuest` as row 2. You will need to pass this information using `userInfo` so that each of it has access to relevant data.

Comment: Another thing is that timer methods execute in a queue. As the activity indicator is created and destroyed within the scope of a synchronous method, don't expect the activity indicator to be active for two rows at the same time. You will have to consider either an NSOperation or a blocks based approach to handle requests in parallel.

Comment: you are seeing it correct=), but i am already passing the rowinformation using userInfo of the timer? or do you mean passing something else?

Comment: Since the beta release is next week, I am not sure if you can change this at this point of time but remember that you can only do one request at the time.

Comment: As per the code above, you are selecting the cell based on `selectedIndexPathFortheGuest` at the very top of the method. That won't be consistent.

Comment: Okej, i know enough know, thank you allot for you help! i really appreciated it!